# Confusion related to k neighborly polytope

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, convex-optimization, polytopes

I was reading this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3660&rep=rep1&type=pdf) related to neighborly polytope where they mentioned:

> Consider a $d \times n$ matrix $A$, with $d < n$. The problem of solving for $x$ in $y = Ax$ is
>   underdetermined, and has many possible solutions (if there are any). In several fields it is
>   of interest to find the sparsest solution – the one with fewest nonzeros – but in general this
>   involves *combinatorial* optimization.
>
> Let $a_i$ denote the $i$-th column of $A$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. Associate to $A$ the
>   quotient polytope $P$ formed by taking the convex hull of the $2n$ points
>   $(±a_i)$ in $\mathbf{R}^d$. $P$ is centrosymmetric and is called (centrally) $k$-neighborly if every subset of $k + 1$ elements $({±}_{il} a_{il})_{l=1}^{k+1}$ are the vertices of a face of $P$.

I didn't get what they mean by $({±}_{il} a_{il})_{l=1}^{k+1}$. Do they mean any $± a_i$?  Each $a_i$ represents a point. Any clarifications?

Also in this [paper](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/recognition/Files/PAMI-Face.pdf) (p. 4) they mention that:

> In general, if $A$ maps all $t$-dimensional facets of $P_1$ to facets
>   of $P$, the polytope $P$ is referred to as (centrally) $t$-neighborly.
>   From the above, we see that the $\ell^1$-minimization correctly
>   recovers all $x_0$ with $\leq t+1$ nonzeros iff $P$ is $t$-neighborly,
>   in which case it is equivalent to the $\ell^0$-minimization.

I didn't get how come mapping t-dimensional facets to P recovers all all $x_0$ with t+1 nonzeros. The max dimension is t. So how come they have t+1 in there?

Any suggestions/clarifications?

Comment: I have an answer to the first question but not the second. The centrosymmetric version of the k-neighborly definition is given in the last sentence, first paragraph [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507280.pdf). Antipodal points in a centrosymmetric polytope can never be the endpoints of an edge because (in the usual representation) their midpoint is the origin, which is in the interior of the polytope. So, antipodal pairs are excluded from consideration in the definition.